# Why won't urls.py pick up my view

Tags: python, regex, django, django-urls

I have urls.py declaration of:

```
(r'^Account/PS/d=^[A-za-z0-9]{2,50}.[a-z]{1,3}$', SAA),
```

I am clicking on a link that looks like:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/Account/PS/d=mydomain.com
```

I've `stopped eclipse's server`, `restarted eclipse`, then `started server`.

I then click that link from above, but it throws  the django "page not found" showing the `urls.py` declarations as of the regex didn't match the url.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take your second `^` out of your regex. Change it to:

```
(r'^Account/PS/d=[A-za-z0-9]{2,50}.[a-z]{1,3}$', SAA),
```

Comment: No prob. Happens to us all.